# Disabling input field when go back to the HTML page

Tags: javascript, html

I have a HTML inputting page that can disable a input field by checking a check box named **undefined**.

When I check undefined and go to next page and come back to the inputting page have to checked the check box and disable the input field.

Now when I come back to input page the **`checkbox` is checked but `input field` is not `disabled`**.

Below is my `javascript` function code and the inputting page code segment. Please help me on this.

`javascript function:`

```
    function disable_input_field(value){    
    var input_field = document.getElementById("person_" + value);     
    if ($("#undefined_" + value).is(":checked")) {       
        input_field.disabled = true;         
        input_field.style.backgroundColor = "#e6e6e6";       
        document.getElementById(value).value = 'undifined';     
    }else{      
        input_field.disabled = false;       
        input_field.style.backgroundColor = "#ffffff";      
        document.getElementById(value).value = '';     
    } 
}
```

Inputting page code segment :

```
<tr>                     
<td nowrap class="auto-style34" colspan="3" style="height: 40px;">data</td>                         
<td nowrap class="auto-style39" colspan="3">                            
    <input type="text" style="background-color: white;color: black;border-style:solid;height: 25;ime-mode: active;" id="person_data" name="person_data" size="50" value='<?php echo person_data ?>'>                     
    </td>                       
    <td nowrap class="auto-style39" colspan = "3">                      
    <?php if($check_data != ''){ print_r("if");?> 
    <input type="checkbox" checked name="undefined_data" id="undefined_data" onclick="disable_input_field('data')" >undefined 
    <?php }else{ print_r("else");?>                             
    <input type="checkbox" name="undefined_data" id="undefined_data" onclick="disable_input_field('data')" >undefined                       
    <?php }?>
    <input type="hidden" name="data" id="data">
    </td>
```

When coming back to the inputting page `$check_data` becomes not null.

Comment: I'm having difficulty understanding your issue here. To start with, is this a typo? Maybe you are using the value somewhere: document.getElementById(value).value = 'und**i**fined';, should be `document.getElementById(value).value = 'undefined';`

Comment: On pageload or DOM-ready you should trigger some JavaScript which evaluates the checkbox state and updates the input accordingly. Because (some?) browsers persist form values if you navigate back.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

if($("#undefined_" + value).is(":checked")){
        input_field.disabled = true;         
        input_field.style.backgroundColor = "#e6e6e6";       
        document.getElementById(value).value = 'undifined';  
}

});
```